# Why did NASA never launch crewed Orion missions on a Delta IV Heavy to the ISS?

Tags: design-alternative, orion-spacecraft, delta-iv-heavy

Following the successful EFT-1 mission, why didn't NASA start launching crews to the ISS on the Orion spacecraft? [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43718/why-isnt-the-delta-iv-heavy-ever-used-for-crewed-spaceflight) deals about why crews weren't sent *to the Moon*, but I wonder why wasn't the Delta IV Heavy with Orion used for manned LEO flights following the retirement of the Space Shuttle and before the Crew Dragon flights started? Is it because the launch pads would have to be rebuilt much? I guess it would have been beneficial for the Artemis program to test the spacecraft in manned flights, similar to Apollo 7.

Comment: The [other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43756/34933) to the linked question may be useful here. Certifying a rocket for crewed spaceflight is a lot of work.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Yes, but you do it _not_ because it is easy, but because it is hard. The same standards to fullfil apply to Crew Dragon or CST-100.

Comment: I don't believe the Delta IV is man-rated.

Comment: Let me point you to a 2009 NASA study: [Human Rated Delta IV Heavy Study Constellation Impacts](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/377875main_081109%20Human%20Rated%20Delta%20IV.pdf). I don't have time to digest it into an answer now, perhaps someone else will. TL;DR: The RS-68 needed extensive changes to be safe enough for human cargo.

Comment: You mentioned CST-100. Are you aware that all remaining Atlas V flights are sold out, and CST-100 is thus without a launch vehicle (after the current contract)?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Um, no? Won't there be another uncrewed test flight soon?